# Jackrabbit XPath subset reference

Tags: xpath, jackrabbit

Did anybody come across a reference doc that would list what is and what is not supported by the Jackrabbit XPath? I see the guys have got quite a [backlog in their JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JCR%20AND%20%28summary%20~%20XPath%20OR%20description%20~%20XPath%20OR%20comment%20~%20XPath%29%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open,%20%22In%20Progress%22,%20Reopened,%20%22Patch%20Available%22%29) of "simple" things like the `count()` function, the `position()` function, half of the axes, etc.

Trying to do some advanced querying with XPath against a Jackrabbit repository now becomes trial and error process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackrabbit supports everything mandated by [JSR-170](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=170). Unfortunately there is no single document of what XPath query features are supported beyond of that. I usually look the features up from the [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-spi-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/spi/commons/query/xpath/XPathQueryBuilder.java?view=markup) and from [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR).